# Terminology: name for integer "factor" of a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, terminology, factoring

Basic terminology question from a non-mathematician. I started trying to express this with mathematical terms, but decided any potential errors might be more frustrating than the imprecision of written language.

Let's say I have a rectangle $Q$ with sides with integer lengths, $a$ and $b$. The rectangle $Q$ can be scaled, dividing the length of each side by the same *rational* scaling factor, resulting in a second rectangle $Q_n$ with the same aspect ratio and with sides of integer length. Is there a name for the relationship between these two rectangles, like "$Q_n$ is an integer factor of $Q$?"

[In case you haven't guessed it, I'm doing some image processing and want to talk about ways of minimizing distortion.]

Comment: So, for example, if the sides of $Q$ are $300,400$ and the sides of $Q_n$ are $225,300$ then you want to say $Q_n$ is a _______ of $Q$, but if $Q_n$ had sides $200,300$ you would say that $Q_n$ is not a _______ of $Q$. Is that a correct understanding of the question?

Comment: Your two rectangles are *similar figures*. You have preserved the *aspect ratio*.

Comment: I'd guess not, but there might be such a term in graphics. The could be called  "similar integer-sided rectangles."

Comment: Preserving the aspect ratio is also true if the rectangles are scaled by a real (non-rational) number and the sides of the scaled rectangle are reals (not integers). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your similar rectangles are integer multiples (scalings) of some common integer rectangle which has sides of coprime lengths (which might possibly also be identical one of the two rectangles, of course).

So there is a "primitive" rectangle $Q_p$ that both $Q$ and $Q_n$ are multiples of. Taking $g_Q= \gcd(a, b)$, $Q_p$ has sides $\left(\frac{a}{g_Q}, \frac{b}{g_Q} \right)$.

To extend the language of integers into this concept, it's not (necessarily) that $Q_n$ is a factor-rectangle of $Q$, or vice versa, but that they have a common factor-rectangle ($Q_p$).